# Are return types instanced or the value simply assigned

Tags: c++, return, return-value

I have been contemplating the answer to my question, so i had to ask, are return types instanced or the value simply assigned?

Take the below sample as example:

```
class Convert {

public:

    int getValue (std::string const& _text);

};


Convert convert;
int total(0);

total = convert.getValue("488");
```

Therefor; what is happening at time the result is being returned from the `getValue()` member function, what are the steps? Is the instance for the return type `int` created and than the value copied from the temporary `int` into the `total` variable, or is the returning value directly assigned into the `total` without needing to create a temporary return type `int`?

Because some of my code has `void getValue (int& _result, std::string const& _text)` ;however, `int getValue (std::string const& _text)` is more logical.

Comment: Either options can be taken based on optimization...as you said return by value is more logical and you should stick to that..its better approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy elision is an allowed optimization that nearly every compiler supports.

Copy elision means that in certain circumstances, what would be the creation of a temporary copy, followed by copying that temporary copy into a named variable, then the destruction of the temporary copy, can instead result in the variable being directly constructed.

Together with return value optimization and move semantics, it means that returning movable complex objects is efficient.  For a type like an `int` the as-if rule also is in operation: the compiler can do anything that behaves as-if the line or block of code was executed, and compilers understand what happens when you copy/move an `int` around (ie, basically nothing), so they can skip those copy/moves.

To ensure that RVO and copy elision occur properly, you want to do something like this:

```
int function() {
  int retval = 8; // create the return value in one spot, this makes NRVO possible
  // code goes here
  return retval; // you can have more than one return statement in most compilers
}

int result = function(); // initialize the variable result by assigning the return value of the function to it.
```

If you do the above, most compilers will construct the `retval` object directly in the `result` variables storage, with no copies occuring at all if `function`'s body can be seen at `result` (some may do it even if you cannot see the body of `function` mayhap)

In C++11 there are other tricks.

```
int function() {
  return {7}; // guaranteed to directly construct the return value without a copy
}

int result = function(); // even if copy elision is not done, the temporary `int` is moved into `result`.
```

And if you block copy elision:

```
int function() {
  int foo = 7;
  int bar = 3;
  // code
  if (foo>bar)
    return foo;
  else
    return bar;
}
```

so long as you return a local variable, implicit move occurs.  You can also explicitly `std::move` into the return value.

Now, for a type as simple and small as `int`, all of these optimizations are pretty pointless.  When you are dealing with larger, expensive objects, like a `std::vector` of `std::vector`s, each of them with 10 MB of data in them, these techniques mean that returning by-value ends up being as efficient as passing in pointers to be carefully filled.

Comment: Thank you Yakk. I say you know the compiler very well! Reading your explanation has turned things i understand upside down in many good ways. I would not guessed that a variable having the same type within a function could get optimized whereby the computation is placed directly into the `result` variable without needing a temporary. ^^ I just have one follow up question, as you say "to ensure that RVO and copy elision occur properly" you have `int result = function();` dose it brake during say a secondary call to the 'function()' like so `result = function();`, without the initialize?

Comment: @8-bitButterfly the second example will copy or move construct.  In the case of a trivial type like int, the compiler will do the same for a copy as a construct, and it can skip any earlier construction because it knows you never read it.

Answer (score 0):

Your full-expression `total = convert.getValue("488");` is an assignment expression. Evaluating it assigns the value on the right to the variable `total`. The value on the right is the result of evaluating the subexpression `convert.getValue("488");`. This value is a temporary value (an rvalue) of type `int`.

I don't really think there's a better way of saying that "the value that's the result of evaluating the right-hand side is assigned to the left-hand side".

An optimizing compiler may very well realize that the class is empty and that the initialization of `total` with `0` is unobservable and fold everything into something very short.